# Inverse of the Composition of elements in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Let $a$, $b$ be in $G$. Is the following true:

$$(a \cdot b)^{-1}=b^{-1} \cdot a^{-1}$$

I don't think it is, but it seems like it must be true for a certain problem.

Comment: It turns out that this is true in general. Hint: Set $x = b^{-1}a^{-1}$, $y = ab$ and show that $xy = 1 = yx$.

Comment: What @MatthiasKlupsch said! However, for a group, one only needs to check $xy=1$.

Answer (score 2):

as $(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})=a(b.b^{-1})a^{-1}=e$ and also the other way so it's true n general

Answer (score 0):

This requires a lemma:

> **Lemma:** (Inverses are unique.) Let $G$ be a group. Let $g\in G$. If $h\in G$ such that $gh=e=hg$, then $h=g^{-1}$.

*Proof:* We have

$$\begin{align}
g^{-1}&=g^{-1}e\\
&=g^{-1}(gh)\\
&=(g^{-1}g)h\\
&=eh\\
&=h. \,\square
\end{align}$$

Now we can prove the theorem:

> **Theorem:** Let $g,h\in G$ for a group $G$. Then $$(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}.$$

*Proof:* By uniqueness of inverses, it is enough to show that $$(gh)\color{red}{(h^{-1}g^{-1})}=e=\color{red}{(h^{-1}g^{-1})}(gh).$$ But

$$\begin{align}
(gh)\color{red}{(h^{-1}g^{-1})}&=g(h(h^{-1}g^{-1}))\\
&=g((hh^{-1})g^{-1})\\
&=g(eg^{-1})\\
&=gg^{-1}\\
&=e\\
&=h^{-1}h\\
&=(h^{-1}e)h\\
&=(h^{-1}(g^{-1}g))h\\
&=((h^{-1}g^{-1})g)h\\
&=\color{red}{(h^{-1}g^{-1})}(gh).\,\square
\end{align}$$